# Google Cloud server (GCE), custom image, SSH login issue

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-14.04

I'm playing with Google Compute Engine(GCE) as I'm planning to migrate the cloud service provider from Rackspace(reason: GCE has good upgrade plans with best discount price).

I have few issues with GCE and one of them is Ubuntu os/image not supported by default. But there is an alternate method to run any linux distro in GCE, which is called [Building an image from scratch](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage) for uploading custom images and creating instances(servers) from uploaded image.

I could able to create and run the instances from the Ubuntu image I uploaded to GCE following the link [hagikuratakeshi.hatenablog.com](http://hagikuratakeshi.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/05/11/004412). This is simply running ubuntu in general. I didn't face any problem but google's gcutil tool prompts for ssh passphrase and adds the key in GCE meta data but accepts only password logins(then why it prompts for passphrase).

I want to strictly follow [Building an image from scratch](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage) as recommended by google. But after following all the steps, I could not able to login to my server instance via SSH. I guess this happens when I install [Google Compute Engine image packages](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/releases): `google-startup-scripts_1.1.2-1_all.deb`, `google-compute-daemon_1.1.2-1_all.deb` & `python-gcimagebundle_1.1.2-1_all.deb`. These packages/scripts make some changes to the instance at the startup and also to SSH configuration which are Strongly recommended. Once I strictly follow the link or once I install these packages I could not able to establish SSH connection once the instance is rebooted. The error message similar to the one below is shown while trying to connect:

```
test@machine1:~$ gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="mypro-555" ssh --zone="asia-east1-a" "server-instance-1"

INFO: Running command line: ssh o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/test/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 test@101.167.xxx.xxx -
ssh: connect to host 101.167.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

NOTE: The user account `test` is available and common on both local and GCE server!.

My main problem is SSH connection when I strictly follow the steps. If I upload the fresh image and then follow the recommended steps connecting SSH, I could not do SSH again once I restart the instance (or) if I setup everything in the uploaded image before uploading, the created instance will be running but I could not able to connect atleast ones and the error is same.

Anybody using GCE with your custom image?, are you allowed to connected even after following the recommended settings?. Anyone already fixed this SSH issue?. Please post your comments!

### EDIT 1

I could not figure out from the logs and here is the output of [gcutil getserialportoutput server-instance-1](http://pastebin.com/nkYjQRnH).

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that your ssh client says "connection refused".  This indicates that there is indeed a machine at that IP address, but it's not accepting SSH connections.  There are a few possible explanations:

1. The ssh daemon isn't running, or is listening on the wrong interface
2. Your instance is configured with a firewall that's denying SSH traffic
3. The GCE firewall rule to allow SSH traffic has been removed

Comment: (1)Before installing GCE image packages, SSH allowed connections.(2)I don't have any iptable rules configured as it's fresh machine.(3)I cross checked many times if there is any entry for ssh in GCE firewall, yes it's by default enabled for everyone. Before applying GCE recommended settings, the new instance will be normally running but once I install the GCE image packages and restart the instance, it shows the connection refused error.

Comment: That's fascinating, and quite unexpected. I'd look closely at the output of `gcutil getserialportoutput <instancename>` for that instance; I hope that it will provide some clues as to what's going on.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me from that log whether the machine has finished booting.  Can you successfully ping it from another GCE instance?

Comment: That's interesting. At this point, I think your best bet is to shut down the instance, but keep the disk.  Then, mount the disk on a new instance from a stock image, and look in /var/log to see if there's anything indicating what might be going on. There's a lot of info on how to do this in the GCE SSH troubleshooting guide: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors